# Python Sending Excel Attachment corrupts file

Tags: python, email, attachment

Using the `ezgmail` library, I am sending an E-mail with an Excel file attached.

I am able to send the E-mail with the attached Excel file, but when I open the Excel file from the sent E-mail, it seems it becomes corrupt for some reason because I get this message:

> We found a problem with some content in 'attached_file.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

When I click "Yes" I get:

> Excel cannot open the file 'attached_file.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

The excel file that I attach opens fine from my desktop, or if I E-mail it manually. I get these prompts only after E-mailing it via my python script which leverages `ezgmail`. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Use a hex viewer or editor to compare the files to find differences. My first guess is a problem around 0x0a or 0x0d bytes (line ending conversion).

Comment: Did you figure this out? Im getting the same issue with epub files. Its only corrupt when I use the python script.